# ADA : Convert an input with slashes to 3 seperate integers

Tags: string, input, integer, ada

How would I go about reading in an input that looks like "01/12/1997" to 3 seperate integers that are 01, 12, and 1997?

Comment: I'd probably use Ada.Strings.Fixed.Index to find the separators, then use the `value'` attribute on the numeric substrings, but there are plenty of other ways. http://www.cs.uni.edu/~mccormic/063/predefined may help.

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Comment: You could use [Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO.Get](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-10-8.html#p15) (that’s the from-string version).

Comment: @TheMrMittens: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).

Answer (score 1):

If using GNAT, you can use [GNAT.String_Split](http://wiki.ada-dk.org/gnat.string_split_basic_usage_example), followed by the 'Value attribute conversion.

Answer (score 1):

And just in case your question was an intermediate step on the way to parsing dates, you should take a look at `GNAT.Calendar.Time_IO.Value` which knows about parsing various dates formats.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding 3 more variables, all strings. I then set them as Date(1..2) and Month(4..5) and Year(7..10), then I converted them all to integers and continued my program. Not the best way, but it worked.

Comment: Problem with this is that it's too vulnerable, either 1/12/1997 or 01/12/97 will misbehave unnecessarily badly. With this approach you need other means of guaranteeing the correct string format - more programming. If you are indeed converting dates, manuBriot's suggestion is the best; use the tools supplied.